# Inno Setup: How to rename system32 files in 64-bit OS

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

System32 and syswow64 folders are exist under C:\Windows in 64-bit OS.

I have a file called `xyz.sys` under `System32\drivers` folder. I tried to rename `xyz.sys` to `xyz1.sys` using below code:

```
if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{sys}\drivers\xyz.sys')) then
  RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{sys}\drivers\xyz.sys'), ExpandConstant('{sys}\drivers\xyz1.sys'));
```

But in 64-bit OS, innosetup is taking `{sys}='Driveletter:\Windows\syswow64'` as default one.

Even i tried below code to rename `xyz.sys` file under `System32\drivers`:

```
if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{win}\System32\drivers\xyz.sys')) then
  RenameFile(ExpandConstant('{win}\System32\drivers\xyz.sys'), ExpandConstant('{win}\System32\drivers\xyz1.sys'));
```

But above code also not working, can anyone suggest me how to rename system32 files in 64-bit OS.

Am using windows2008R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default 32-bit applications (and installers for 32-bit apps) can only access the 32-bit system folder.  You can use the `64bit` flag on various entries to override this, if there is a specific 64-bit file you need to install for a 32-bit application, for example.

You can do the same thing from `[Code]` by using the [`EnableFsRedirection`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_enablefsredirection.htm) support function.  That help page shows an example of executing the 64-bit command prompt; you can similarly access the 64-bit `{sys}` from within that block.  Don't forget to restore the previous state afterwards, as shown.

Bear in mind however that renaming an installed driver file is generally not a good idea -- there will be catalog and INF files still pointing to its old name, and the system may get confused by this.  It's better to properly uninstall the driver and reinstall the new one.

Comment: I've never seen `{sys64}` before, looks useful, do you have a pointer to any documentation on it? I can't find it in the docs I'm referencing :)

Comment: Sorry, I was getting mixed up with `{pf64}` and `{syswow64}` (the latter of which is actually the 32-bit system folder).  I've corrected my answer, including a help link.

Comment: thank you miral, my code is working fine with your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

InnoSetup runs the install in 32 bit mode unless you set [ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_architecturesinstallin64bitmode) to `x64`.

If you want access to the 64-bit files using `{sys}`, you should set that value.

More explanation under the `{sys}` heading [at the docs](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).

Comment: Note that you should only set that value if your application itself is 64-bit.  If your application is 32-bit but installs or needs to manipulate a 64-bit driver, there are other ways to do this.